# adding nuget package DOTNETOPENAUTH to a universal windows application

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

I'm just starting to work with Universal Apps in VS2015 (C#).  Nuget is on version 3.3.  I was able to install the package Newtonsoft.json through nuget with no issues.  However, when I try to install DotNetOpenAuth I get a message "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'TestLibrary'.  I have nuget auto package restore turned on.  If I run install-package DotNetOpenAuth from the package manager console I get:

> install-package : DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.UI 4.3.4.13329 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> install-package DotNetOpenAuth
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> install-package : DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.UI 4.3.4.13329 is not  compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
>
> At line:1 char:1

for each of the components it tries to install.

Is DotNetOpenAuth not compatible with Universal Apps or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOTNETOPENAUTH is meant as an ASP.NET helper, and it requires the entire .NET framework. You wouldn't be able to access it from a universal app since you don't have the entire .NET framework, just .NET Core plus some other functionality (subsets of WPF, etc.).  It is more meant as an extension for ASP apps, although it is supported in full .NET Framework apps.

Your error message indicates that it's not currently published to NuGet as a package for the Universal Windows App platform.

If you want to do OAuth in a universal app (without working to make DOTNETOPENAUTH compatible yourself), you'd have to find a library that would support that functionality.  This seems to be a potential resource: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAuthenticationBroker

Comment: Thank you; that's what I needed to know.

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth's [site](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) specifically says "Easy access to all the functionality so you can customize how OpenID will operate on your site,whether you use ASP.NET or not." That implies that it doesn't necessarily need System.Web.

Comment: Sure thing.  Keep an eye out for .NET Core, they are trying to modularize ASP.NET and break the dependency on IIS, and at that point there may be a way to reuse libraries like this one.

Comment: @mason appears to be correct, I apologize. This seems like a helper for using DotNetOpenAuth outside of ASP: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dotnetopenid/aHfGU5oWE70

Comment: Feel free to un-accept my answer, I will delete it once you read this reply and let us know.  Sorry to mis-inform. Either way, the error you received means that this library isn't published to NuGet in a form that's compatible with UAP, so in your specific case you would have to come up with another solution anyway.

Comment: I was only looking for yes I can use it or no I can't and need to go down another path.  I was hoping for dotnetopenauth because I've got a history with it.  I guess I'll work with another package. Thanks again.

Comment: ok, in that case I will edit the answer to be more clear in case someone sees it later.